# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Width' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue dynamically setting the width of a ul element in my website.

Below is the jQuery I'm uusing

```
var button = $("#navbar");
alert(button);
var count = $("#header li").length;
alert(count);
$("#navbar").style.Width = count * 110
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix hidden">
        <img src="/Content/Images/main-logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="home">
                home
            </li>
            <li id="portfolio">
                portfolio
            </li>
            <li id="about">
                about
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "alert(button)" returns [object Object] so it's not null (at least my understanding of it) but I get the error mentioned in the title whenever I try to set the width of it.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use one of the following code

```
$("#navbar")[0].style.width = count * 110
```

or

```
$("#navbar").width(count * 110)
```

because the `style` is the property of DOM element while `$("#navbar")` is a jquery object, which does not contain the `style` property by default.

Answer (score 1):

`style` is a DOM property but not a property of jQuery objects. If you want to set the width using jQuery you'd use either the [css getter/setter](http://api.jquery.com/css/) or the [width function](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value) directly.

```
$("#navbar").width(count * 110);
$("#navbar").css('width', (count * 110) + "px");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working on a jQuery element by using `$("#navbar")`. If you want to set the width using vanilla javascript:

```
$("#navbar")[0].style.width = count * 110  //note that the width property is not capitalized
```

Or use jQuery's `width` method:

```
$("#navbar").width(count * 110);
```